# Provider configuration set number of messages to prefectch

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am new to spring boot jms and i saw something like provider configuration - > set Number of messages to prefetch function, i could not find much about it and i don't have much clear idea as to what does it mean?

I have my concurrency set to 5-100. So does it mean, everytime a new consumer is spawned, this will get the number of messages, lets say if i set it 5, will it get 5 messages from queue at once?

Without using spring jms we use to make a receive call which can fetch upto 10 message, over here we have a jms listener, are these two same?

Can anyone clarify its real purpose in terms of multiple consumers, what it will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the prefetch applies to each consumer.

Using multiple consumers allows you to process messages is parallel to improve performance, but you can only do that if the order in which you process messages is not important.

Comment: So how does it work, does it prefectch and maintains small queue inside it or what?

Comment: Let's say there are 50 messages and i do prefectch 10 messages and my concurrency is 50(min). So it will invoke 5 consumers and rest will sit idle? If yes. Does each thread store this prefetching somewhere?

Comment: It's not part of the JMS spec; in general, brokers send 'prefetch' messages to the `MessageConsumer` implementation; Spring knows nothing about it; it simply calls `receive()` on the consumer and the client hands it a message. Generally, yes, the client jar will store the prefetched messages in memory, locally.

Comment: Okay. I have few doubts, regarding some more if jms, i couldn't find any thing on web properly. Can we do a group chat kind of thing here, i would really appreciate it. Won't take much of your good time sir. :)

Comment: I am trying to implement sqs listener with concurrency 50-100 and trying to achieve a TPS of 800-1000, is it achievable?. If yes, can you point me in the right direction. If not what should i do for it. To get SQS messages at 1000 TPs.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide 1:1 support - I am not familiar with SQS so I don't know what is achievable with it but, generally, bottlenecks are likely in user code.

Comment: I am able to achieve 250 Tps with it.. More than that, i am not able to do it. It's okay. Can you tell me one thing though i am getting a port already in use after getting around 17k messages. When can thjs happen on multi thread environment?

Comment: Again; I am not familiar with SQS; if you are also publishing messages from this app, you should use a `CachingConnectionFactory` to avoid opening a new connection for each publish.