# In amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib, what is the difference of numberOfMessagesToPrefetch 0 or 1?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

This question is about the library https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib. This library can be used for accessing AWS SQS, it is provided by AWS itself.

The library supports [prefetching of messages](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/ProviderConfiguration.java). I wonder, what values have which impact here. The default is set to 1.

Which impact do the following value for numberOfMessagesToPrefetch have?

- 0
- 1
- > 1

Answer (score 3):

`Prefetching` of messages into a local buffer that allows your application to immediately process messages from Amazon SQS without waiting for the messages to be retrieved.

`numberOfMessagesToPrefetch` Determine the number of messages we should attempt to fetch from SQS. 
These numbers are configurable

```
MAX_BATCH = 10;
MIN_BATCH = 1;
```

After the first `receiveMessage` call is made, the client attempts not only to satisfy that call, but also pre-fetch extra messages to store in a temporary buffer. Future receiveMessage calls will be satisfied from the buffer, and only if the buffer is empty will the calling thread have to wait for the messages to be fetched.

[Client-Side Buffering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-client-side-buffering-request-batching.html)

[Another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726125/5703813)

Comment: Your second link "Another Stackoverflow answer" points to the same URL as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you step through the library you end up at this method [`AmazonSQS#receiveMessage(ReceiveMessageRequest)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQS.html#receiveMessage-com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest-)

which further links to [API_ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html).

From there you get the info that values between 1 and 10 are acceptable values.

The library seems to transfer any message it receives to an internal `ArrayDeque` from which you can retrieve the messages. The limiting factor of that queue is the `numberOfMessagesToPrefetch` you orginally configured.

If you use a value larger than 10 continous calls will be made, till the queue is completly filled.

---

Passing 0 means that there is no prefetch. Messages will be retrieve when the `SQSMessageConsumer#receive` method is called. As its synchronized internally I assume it most likely ends up calling `AmazonSQS#receiveMessage` with a value of 1.

---

Another point to note is that when you're using the [`SQSMessageConsumer#receive`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/SQSMessageConsumer.java#L148) method you can only retrieve one message at a time. So eventually the calls to `AmazonSQS#receiveMessage` might end up only retrieving 1 message at a time, assuming the case where the buffer is always full and sufficient messages are available (e.g. under high load).

Comment: Value of "0" seems to be valid from the lib point of view. There was just a released which handled a bug related to numberOfMessagesToPrefetch=0, see https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/releases/tag/1.0.7

Comment: Yes, seems before I missed the part were the `SQSMessagePrefetchConsumer` increments the `messagesRequested` variable, which basically means passing `0` is basically the same as `1` (just without the prefetch).